# Merging two tables and returning value through r script

Tags: r, spotfire

I am attempting to add a dynamic column to a table in spotfire that is updated using r-script/data functions in order to handle different variable types.  When you just insert columns, it does not allow you to change the column from a text value to a string value.

The basic code structure is create a new table by merging the base table with the information table, select a column header to populate the new column from, and return the calculated column values to the base table. Parameters are as follows:

Input Parameters:

```
Name            Type 
columnMatch     Value
baseTable       Table
infoTable       Table
```

Output Parameters (to be added to baseTable)

```
Name            Type
outputColumn    Column
```

Script

```
newTable <- merge(baseTable,infoTable, by = "uniqueIdentifier")
cnames <- colnames(newTable)
outputColumn <- newTable[,match(colorSelection, cnames, nomatch=1)] 

outputColumn
```

The issue thatI am having is as follows:

- The code is not returning the correct value for the correct uniqueIdentifier.  Is there a way that I can make the values line up, or sort the table in order to return the correct value for the correct uniqueIdentifier?

Thanks!

Jordan

EDIT: found out how to dynamically refer to column number  using match function.

Comment: 1. do you mean `newTable[,"columnMatch"]` ? 2. you will have to show some data,

Comment: Scoa, columnMatch is a document property that the user can set through column selection from the infoTable.  I tried using columnMatch as a variable but I get a runtime error.

Comment: @JSS - did you post the naswer you found out somewhere or just the info that you did ?

Comment: @JacekSierajewski Still having trouble figuring this one out - the issue now is that the return column is not indexed to the input table correctly.  Spotfire isn't preserving order when I output the values